# Unable to get MPEG-DASH working using cast-android-sample

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm having difficulty getting a mpeg-dash sample to play properly using the [cast-android-sample](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample).

It's easily reproduced by adding a dash sample to the [MediaAdapter:addVideos() method](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample/blob/master/src/com/example/castsample/MediaAdapter.java#L52).  Here are 3 well known MPEG-DASH samples that we used to try to get it working:

```
mVideos.add(new CastMedia("Car MPEG-DASH Video", "http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/car-20120827-manifest.mpd"));
mVideos.add(new CastMedia("Simple MPEG-DASH Video", "http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/DASH_CONFORMANCE/TelecomParisTech/mpeg2-simple/mpeg2-simple-mpd.mpd"));
mVideos.add(new CastMedia("MPEG-DASH Sample", "http://www.digitalprimates.net/dash/streams/gpac/mp4-main-multi-mpd-AV-NBS.mpd"));
```

Attempting to play these generates an error of this form in the logcat:

```
18147-18147/com.example.castsample E/MediaProtocolMessageStream: error parsing message: {"type":"RESPONSE","cmd_id":24,"status":{"error":{"domain":"ramp","code":-2},"event_sequence":6499}} org.json.JSONException: No value for state
```

Note that the mp4s listed in the demo do in fact work - so I know I've got the cast-android-sample code working in general. Additionally I've tried hosting the files - and by monitoring the access logs I know that the mpd is fetched and that the media referenced by the mpd is never accessed by the device.

Is there something else that needs to be done to get MPEG-DASH media to play from Chromecast?  Can someone provide a working example from this code-base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should work with the Dash Industry associations [player](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki).  We support all of Chrome's Media Source Events.

Comment: How much code are we talking about here?  To be a complete answer, SO moderators generally perfer that the whole answer be posted (in this case, the code sample), instead of a contact e-mail address.  If others are in the same boat, they shouldn't be forced to contact `chromecast-updates@google.com` as well.

Comment: I agree, but that's the best I can offer at this point, it's several files of javascript.

Comment: So how would this work from an android standpoint?  If I had an mpeg-dash or smoothstreaming url and wanted to cast it from android would I have to have a html + javascript page that would actually do the work and send that to chromecast instead of the url of the mpeg-dash stream?