# How to play smooth streaming video in Chromecast?

Tags: smooth-streaming, google-cast

According the Chromecast Developers page, Chromecast supports the SmoothStreaming container, which I believe uses video chunks with the .ismv extension.  I am having problems getting those video files to play.

If I am not mistaken, Chrome/Chromecasts's implementation of the video tag only supports .mp4 and .webm files, so using cast.MediaLoadRequest (in a Chrome Sender App) would not work if you pass it a url for a manifest file or .ismv container.

It does seem possible to write code that stitches together MPEG-DASH chunks using the [MediaSource API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) from a MPEG-DASH manifest file.  However, it doesn't appear that Chrome's implementation of the MediaSource spec supports .ismv chunks and therefore a means to play smooth streaming video.

Assuming you parsed a manifest file to get the smooth streaming video chunks, how would it be possible for Chromecast to play .ismv h.264 containers, such as the ones that can be found [here](http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/)?   Or does Chrome not support .ismv files?  If so, what SmoothStreaming containers does Chrome/Chromecast support?

Answer (score 1):

Chromecast supports MPEG-DASH and Smooth Streaming.  See more detail here:

https://developers.google.com/cast/supported_media_types

We'll provide some code snippet of smooth streaming soon. Stay tuned.

Comment: Does it support master playlist files? Eg. "`.mpd`" file for MPEG-DASH, and "`manifest`" file for SmoothStreaming?

Answer (score 0):

The default Receiver provided does not support SmoothStreaming (nor MPEG-DASH).

You'll need to code your own receiver to do so.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978070/2665789 for a little more help.

Hopefully Google posts working samples of Live streaming soon!

Answer (score 0):

You can throw SmoothStreaming to some sample receivers provided by Google.
The [cast-custom-receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver/blob/master/sample_media_receiver.html) and the [Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample/blob/master/MediaPlayerLibrarySample.html) supports SS with PlayReady encryption out of the box.

Well, you need to do some tricks like modify the extension from "ism/" to "ism/Manifest" and it just work. You'll need to do the same in the [cast-sender-tool-chrome] adding the file extension to the list of three inside the main html file.