# Chromecast support for Smooth Streaming with PlayReady

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, smooth-streaming, playready

I'm aware that developer-preview of Chromecast receiver <del>does not fully support Smooth Streaming manifest URL</del> *(See Update#1)*.

I have tested content provided by [Microsoft PlayReady(TM) Test Server - Smooth Streaming assets](http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/) using sample `receiver` app provider in [GitHub project](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample).

### Smooth Streaming Support

<del>As expected, `manifest` file does not work</del> *(See Update#1)*. But I was able to play individual `ismv` file (but only low bitrates). When I use higher bitrate, the video container stays black.

### PlayReady Support

When I tried to play `PlayReady` protected low bitrate `ismv` file, I was expecting some sort of call back `MediaProtocolMessageStream.onKeyRequested()`. But there did not happen. Here is my android [CustomMediaProtocolMessageStream](https://github.com/amardeshbd/cast-android-sample/blob/master/src/com/example/castsample/mediastream/CustomMediaProtocolMessageStream.java) implementation.

---

So, does anybody know how `PlayReady` or `Widevine` supposed to work with Chromecast? I have seen Netflix invokes some binary shell command when app is loaded in chromecast. But I assume, they worked with Google to accomplish this.

### Additional SO Resources

- [How to play smooth streaming video in Chromecast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095444/how-to-play-smooth-streaming-video-in-chromecast)
- [Is it actually possible to play SmoothStreaming videos on Chromecast without using (format=mpd-time-csf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297206/is-it-actually-possible-to-play-smoothstreaming-videos-on-chromecast-without-usi)
- [Playing Smoothstreaming URL by providing Manifest file of smoothstreaming to Chromecast device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358102/playing-smoothstreaming-url-by-providing-manifest-file-of-smoothstreaming-to-chr)

**Update #1**

Based on Les Vogel's answer, smooth streaming manifest file for adaptive bitrate streaming is supported by Chromecast. You need custom player to handle that.
As far as I am aware of, currently there are two JS player which can handle that, but I don't know if they will work on Chromecast.

1. `dash.js` - By DASH Industry Forum (https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js)
2. `Microsoft HTML5 Player Framework` - Part of Microsoft Media Platform (http://playerframework.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you need to write your own media player to support adaptive bitrate streaming on Chromecast.

Unfortunately, the MS test server assets do not correctly provide a CORS header, which would be needed if you wrote a javascript player.

PlayReady and Windvine are both supported.  We'll be providing additional documentation shortly.

**EDIT** We announced the beta of the Cast [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) today 2/3/14 - it supports HLS, SmoothStreaming, and MPEG Dash.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you aware of any community supported JS player that is able to handle smoothstreaming manifest files? On one of the SO question, I saw you mentioning `dash.js`. Is that an option?

Comment: Some developers have started with dash.js, but moved on to their own work.

Comment: Thanks for the update on media player library. Is there an example how encrypted media and license acquisition flow works? It seems, we need to use the player's "`Host - Host used for interacting with the application by the player.`" to provide the license, there are APIs like, "`prepareLicenseRequest`", "`processLicense`", "`updateLicenseRequestInfo`"
And the "`Player`" object also has API "`startLicenseRequest() - Tells the player to start requesting the license.`". Is there any example project being done on this area?

Comment: I was not able to use the example android projects on github, since Google Play Services Library v15 is not released yet.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample for a sample Receiver.  It really doesn't show license request, however.  For PlayReady, you can include all the info that's needed in your Manifest, and it will just work -- no need for the extra API's.  If you need CustomData, however, you'll want to go into them.  You do, however, need to enable CORS headers on your servers and CDN's.

Comment: This should work. In the cast developer console I can see requests to DRM server extracted from **ProtectionHeader**.

But how about fully custom license acquisition flow? In our case we have a host which checks user session before requesting a license. There are some references in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040027/chromecast-playready-encryption), but I can't really find anything more.

Comment: You can modify the URL's before they are sent, and you can add custom data to be signed by the Chromecast before it get's sent to your server.  Your Q doesn't contain enough info for me to answer, but you can look at cast.player.api.Host https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/ and find the getLicenseCustomData, licenseCustomData, licenseUrl, prepareLicenseRequest, processLicense, and other methods there.

Comment: Les, I'll try to rephrase - I want receiver to ask sender for license (ios). Do you think it's possible?

Comment: You can create a custom protocol, and communicate between the iOS & the Chromecast.  You can then hook the results into the Media Player Library.  You really should ask this as a separate question so that Ali and Shawn can give you answers.

Comment: Thank you Les! I've created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188003/chromecast-sender-as-a-license-provider. I believe you are talking about custom sender<->receiver protocol, not streaming protocol, right?

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel Grateful if you can ask Ali or Shawn to look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188003/chromecast-sender-as-a-license-provider.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "com.microsoft.playready" for PlayReady and "com.widevine.alpha" for widevine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what are these and where to get it? I can't find any reference in https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/ - Thanks

Comment: That was in reference to the question from @user3253638; read the specs that he had mentioned to familiarize yourself with EME and hopefully then that will make more sense to you.