# Chromecast playready encryption

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast, playready

When i try to play encrypted SmoothStreaming URL http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/SSWSS720H264PR/SuperSpeedway_720.ism/Manifest
on my CastVideos-android sample with cast-custom-receiver, in console (:9222) i get

```
[  8.788s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeysManager] onNeedKey
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.798s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeysManager] onNeedKey_: 1
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.803s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeySession] createSession
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.808s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeysManager] onNeedKey
 media_player.js:24
 [  8.811s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeysManager] onNeedKey_: 2.
```

How to pass a function from here (example 9.2.1. Clear Key) 
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html#examples and feed media_player with data?
Something like this does not work

```
<video src="foo.webm" autoplay onneedkey="handleKeyNeeded(event)"></video>.
```

Also, what to pass here xmlhttp.open("POST", "[url]"); as url in order to play content from abovementioned URL?

Comment: You opened a bug on our issue tracker and I responded to you there.

Comment: I didn't, maybe someone else did that. Which issue ID is that?

Comment: Whomever opened that issue (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=169) has identical username as yours: vanste25

Comment: You are right, however, this time i am interested in streaming encrypted content. So far, i am able to cast using all three protocols without encryption.

Comment: Have you read through the Media Player Library (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) to see if that covers your question or not? If it doesn't, then please open an issue on our tracker.